# Sending Windows commands using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line

tried googling this one but never got the specific answers I needed. So basically I want to develop a NodeJS app on Window that will receive http requests (Rest API style) and translate them to command line commands with arguments to trigger stuff. Is there any tutorial or a specific NodeJS package I can use to do it? Cheers, Pavel

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `.spawn()` or `.exec()` in the [child process module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).  The referenced doc page contains an example for running an `ls` command via node.js which you can likely change into whatever command line you want.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

You will need to be very careful with what you're doing to avoid any means of your server getting compromised.

Comment: Interesting.. Any resource on what are the best practices for these scenarios? Thanks!

Comment: @PavelZagalsky - best practices for what exactly?

Comment: @PavelZagalsky You may also find interesting shelljs package. https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs

Comment: I am looking for Windows commands though, not the UNIX ones. For example if I want to trigger certain files copying or editing etc..

Comment: @PavelZagalsky - The devil is all in the details of exactly what commands you're running and how you get the arguments.  There's no general solution.

Comment: @PavelZagalsky - Seriously.  Do you not see that you just change the program name from `ls` to something different that you want to run and the arguments to something appropriate for the command you're running?  For someone who provided ZERO specifics in your question about what you're trying to run, it seems like you're expecting us to read your mind about what you're doing.  This is a running example, you can just change a few strings in to run your desired Windows command.

Comment: Alright, I saw the UNIX commands and thought it's a UNIX specific solution.